# which is best option to publish android app with local database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an app in which i would need a local database.

So as per my knowledge there are two ways to do it:

First is to add pre filled database file in assets folder & make copy of local database from it the very first time app is started.

Second is using script to download it from Server for first time of app use?

First way have been pretty well answered by this guy [Using your own sqlite database in android application](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Can someone help how can i go with second way of download data from Server?

Should i use JSON/XML for getting that data from my Server?

Or should i go with first option since my app has only around 150 to 200 rows in the db file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for the local db for the following reasons:

1. The users would have great on boarding experience as they can very quickly start seeing the utility of the app since you provide some data on first run without any delay that might be added when you fetch data from the server.
2. Do it for sure if the db doesn't increase the apk size significantly.

Answer (score 0):

You must use php only if you need get information from the server, with php and json is better ...
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

and if you only need share local information, only needs use MYsqLite ...

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: There are tons of other options. You can build your backend for Google App Engine in java and publish it from Android Studio for example...